# react using local storage on inital state for specific user

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello i have problem with my code
i have a bank project and i need to save the specific user on local storage because if i will reload the page it will cause errors
so i need to save it
and the problem is the inital state of users is empty array
so it add to the local storage but after reload of the page the inital state go back to empty array
if i will make the local storage get item on the inital state of the users
i will get error because my specific user that search for it will get error because it will look for array

```
import { useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
export const DataContext = createContext();
export const useDataProvider = () => {
  return useContext(DataContext);
};

const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const specificUser = users.find((user) => user.username === specificUsername);

 sessionStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(specificUser));

// sign in page
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Authentication from "../../components/authentication_sign/AuthenticationSign";
import { useDataProvider } from "../../context/Data";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const SignInPage = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { setSpecificUsername,isUsernameExist } = useDataProvider();
  const handleClick = (data) => {
    const { username, password } = data;
    if (username === "Admin" && password === "1111") return navigate("/admin");
    if (!isUsernameExist(username)) return setError("user not found");
    setSpecificUsername(username);
    
    navigate("/user/current-account");
  };
  return <Authentication userError={error} onClick={handleClick} text={"sign in"} />;
};

export default SignInPage;

// loan page 

const Loan = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { loanMoney,changeLanguage } = useDataProvider();
  const user =JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('key'))
  const { username, income } = user;
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const inpData = [{ name: "price", type: "number" }];
  const maxLoan = Math.floor((income * 70) / 100);
  const handleClick = (data) => {
    if (data.price > maxLoan) return setError("request has been declined");
    loanMoney(username, Number(data.price));
    navigate("/user/current-account");
  };
  return (
    <UserPage>
      <Input
      text={'loan'}
        inpNumber={1}
        inpData={inpData}
        error={error}
        onClick={handleClick}
        rules={{ required: "fill please", minLength: { value: 2, message: "must be at least 2 char" } }}
      />
      <h2>{changeLanguage('max loan')} {maxLoan} ₪</h2>
    </UserPage>
  );
};

export default Loan;
```

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage keeps the data only during a session, so it is reseted when you reload the page.
Use localStorage instead and it will persist even when reloading the page.

Edit: Well, i'm wrong, sessionStorage persist over page refresh.

Comment: i am pretty sure the sessionStorage will keep the data if you reload
if you close the browser it reset the data
am i wrong?

Comment: yes, you are right.
Isn't specificUsername undefined in DataProvider function? Where is it declared?

Comment: its declare i just didnt add the whole code because its a medium project 

i try to navigate you to my problem 
i have sessionStorage set item  that take  "specificUser" 
and specificUser is find method that look username equal to "specificUsername"
the problem is on the first sign in i take the correct user on the session local storage
but after reload the specificUser (where use find) it will go back to empty array because the inital state of users is empty array
at the code i upload it show you the varible/function that i write and maybe it will help

*** specificUsername is state

Comment: At what point does your `users` state change so that instead of an empty `[]`, it's actually a list of users? I'm trying to better understand your problem here because to me, it sounds like instead of always initializing the state with an empty `[]`, you should be doing something a bit more dynamic (i.e., get/load list of users) and only using the `[]` as a fallback.